# Converting a set to a string

Tags: python

So I'm supposed to create a function that takes any sort of iterable input and converts it into a string of that input separated by spaces. For example, if you were to call iteration_to_string("abcd") it would return "a b c d " (the space at the end is allowed). or if [1, 2, 3, 4] is the input, it should return "1 2 3 4 ". All I have so far is how to turn the input into a set and Im confused where to go to turn it into a string. I assume it would be adding something into the for loop that would somehow concatenate the inputs together with a space but Im not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated!

```
    def iteration_to_string (data):
        new = set()

        for i in range (len(data)):
            new.add(data[i])


        return " ".join(new)
```

Comment: `" ".join(new)`, but remember that sets are unordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code might not work for list containing element int like [1,2,3,4] because join takes string

so you can convert them to int before join like this:

```
>>> def my_join(x):
...     return " ".join(map(str, x))
... 
>>> my_join([1, 2, 3, 4])
'1 2 3 4'
```

you can use list comprehension, if you dont want to use map

```
 >>> def my_join(x):
 ...     return " ".join(str(element) for element in x))

>>> my_join(['a', 'b' ,'c', 'd'])
'a b c d'
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without using map()?
I haven't learned that before

Comment: yes you can using list comprehension, see my updated post

Answer (score 1):

for any iterable

```
' '.join(iterable)
```

will return a string with all the elements in iterable separated by a space. refer to [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

if the elements in iterable are not strings you need to

```
' '.join(str(item) for item in iterable)
```

(you can do this with any other string as well; `''.join(iterable)` if you do not want any spaces in between).

Comment: That didn't change anything when I added it to the code. Should it have gone in the for loop? (see above edits)

Comment: rather: `return ' '.join(new)`. `new` remains unchanged; the expression returns a `str`. or `new_str = ' '.join(new); return new_str`.

Comment: That works if you have a string input, but not if its a list or set input

Comment: @Hackaholic oops you are right. updated the  answer which is pointless actually as it is now the same answer as yours.